# How can I get a "reasonable" string sorting with Python?

Tags: python, sorting, natsort

I have users (mostly Germans) who need to select elements from a long list. I will implement autocompletion, but I also want to present them the elements in the order they expect. I asked a couple of users for typical strings to sort them and found that it is (mostly) consistent. However, it is difficult to implement this ordering:

```
user_expectation(l)                               "        <        @        1        2        10       10abc    A        e        é        E        Z
sorted(l)                                         "        1        10       10abc    2        <        @        A        E        Z        e        é
sorted(l, key=lambda w: w.lower())                "        1        10       10abc    2        <        @        A        e        E        Z        é
ns.natsorted(l)                                   1        2        10       10abc    "        <        @        A        E        Z        e        é
ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.I)                         1        2        10       10abc    "        <        @        A        E        Z        e        é
ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G)     1        2        10       10abc    "        <        @        A        E        e        Z        é
ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G), en 1        2        10       10abc    <        "        @        A        E        e        é        Z
ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G), de 1        2        10       10abc    <        "        @        A        E        e        é        Z
ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LF | ns.G), de             1        2        10       10abc    "        <        @        A        e        E        Z        é
```

Hence:

- Special characters first - the order does not really matter, as long as it is consistent
- Numbers next. Sort numbers numerically by matching the prefix (hence ['1', '10', '2'])
- Characters (Latin1?)

  - Non-accented first
  - Lower-case before capital case (though that is probably not so important
  - Accented / special ones later

### Code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import natsort as ns
import locale

def custom_print(name, l):
    s = u"{:<50}".format(name)
    for el in l:
        s += u"{:<5}\t".format(el)
    print(u"\t" + s.strip())

l = ['"', "<", "@", "1", "2", "10", "10abc", "A", "e", "é", "E", "Z"]
custom_print("user_expectation(l)", l)
custom_print("sorted(l)", sorted(l))
custom_print("sorted(l, key=lambda w: w.lower())",
             sorted(l, key=lambda w: w.lower()))
custom_print("ns.natsorted(l)", ns.natsorted(l))
custom_print("ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.I)", ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.I))
custom_print("ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G)",
             ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G))
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
custom_print("ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G), en",
             ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G))
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
custom_print("ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G), de",
             ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LOCALE | ns.LF | ns.G))
custom_print("ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LF | ns.G), de",
             ns.natsorted(l, alg=ns.LF | ns.G))
```

`natsort` with the `IGNORECASE`, `LOWERCASEFIRST`, `LOCALE` (de or en), `GROUP` [flags](http://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ns_class.html) is pretty close. What I don't like is that special characters are after numbers. Is there a way to fix it? (and `LF` seems not to have an effect)

Comment: Should all special characters be after numbers, or just if the string is only the special character?  For example, would both "@" and "@hello" come before "1"?

Comment: All special characters should come before numbers. So both, "@" and "@hello" should come before "1".

Comment: Can you update the user's expected order in your question so that copy/paste gives shows the correct results?

Comment: Based on your response to my comment users would expect `1, 2, 10`, not `1, 10, 2`, but in both examples in the question they still show the latter and not the former.

Comment: @SethMMorton Thank you  It is too early in the morning ... now it should be correct.

Comment: Well asked, glad to see that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As of `natsort` version >= 5.1.0, accented characters should be handled out-of-the-box.

Here is a way to get the special characters ahead of the numbers.

```
import re
import natsort as ns

def special_chars_first(x):
    '''Ensure special characters are sorted first.'''
    # You can add error handling here if needed.
    # If you need '_' to be considered a special character,
    # use [0-9A-Za-z] instead of \W.
    return re.sub(r'^(\W)', r'0\1', x)
    # An alternate, less-hacky solution.
    #if re.match(r'\W', x):
    #    return float('-inf'), x
    #else:
    #    return float('inf'), x

l = ['"', "<", "@", "1", "2", "10", "10abc", "A", "e", "é", "E", "Z"]
print(ns.natsorted(l, key=special_chars_first, alg=ns.G | ns.LF))
```

Output

```
['"', '<', '@', '1', '2', '10', '10abc', 'A', 'e', 'é', 'E', 'Z']
```

This works by prefixing any string that begins with a non-word character (defined as anything except letters, numbers, or `'_'`) with a `'0'` which will guarantee they end up before any other number (and numbers are always first according to now `natsort` works).

Comment: The ability to normalize data should be built-in to `natsort`. I have opened an issue for this: https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/44

Comment: Your special characters first solution will break when there’s a list item that starts with `00`.

Comment: I disagree. I just added `"00@"` to the given list and get the output `['"', '<', '@', '00@', '1', ...]`.

Comment: Odd… but well, just add `"00"` to the list then.

Comment: @poke It wouldn't be a very robust natural sorting algorithm if adding a few leading zeros messed things up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` parameter to replace special characters with something that sorts before numbers (eg a space).

`sorted` (or `natsorted`) would then sort by the modified string, but would still return the original.

A simplified example, that only deals with the special characters vs numbers.

```py
import re
def replace_special(s):
  # add more characters to regex, as required
  return re.sub('[<@]', ' ', s)

l = ['"', "<", "@", "1", "10", "2", "10abc", "A", "e", "é", "E", "Z"]

sorted(l, key=replace_special)
['<', '@', '"', '1', '10', '10abc', '2', 'A', 'E', 'Z', 'e', 'é']
```